# Why my JScrollPane is different from the example?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to learn a bit of Swing and i'm trying [14.46.2.Add component to JScrollPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddcomponenttoJScrollPane.htm) example. The code is this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class AddingToJScrollPane {

public static void main(String args[]) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane Sample");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
  label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
  JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);

  JButton jButton1 = new JButton();

  jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
  jScrollPane.getViewport().add(jButton1, null);

  frame.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.setSize(400, 150);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

From the page you can see what is the expected result.

[image]

However, just copy&pasting that code, I get the result in the image below. I'm trying to understand if the example is out of date or the example image is wrong (where's the red border on the tutorial image?). Moreover, my scrollbars are not enabled whiley I'm expecting that they are. Am i missing something to get them enabled (in the tutorial they are ok)? I'm using JDK7.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK to see the red border, it is caused by this line:

```
jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
```

As a background info, you should be aware that setting a colored line border to components is a useful debugging possibility in Swing (otherwise it is often hard to see where one component ends and another starts), so here the author probably wanted to debug something after taking the screenshot, and forgot to remove this line from the code.

BTW, if you want to learn Swing, the best online resource is the "official" one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

EDIT: the scrollbars are enabled, it is not like they are "greyed out", there is a visual change if you click on the arrows. There is nothing to scroll, because the button is always resized to the size of the visible area. As I said, this is not a good example, don't learn from here...

Comment: going to edit question since I need also to undestand why scrollbars differ.

Comment: ok, going to start ove from oracle tutorial, ironically I found that tutorial from another SO +1'd answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is ok and the bordar is Red

```
jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
```

and the image in the link is wrong image

Comment: and what about scrollbars? going to specify better my question. Scrollbars are not enabled